# Swift: inputAccessoryView buttons are not showing

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibarbuttonitem, inputaccessoryview

Following is my code for adding an inputAccessoryView (with a Done button on it) to my textView:

```
let keyboardButtonView = UIToolbar()
keyboardButtonView.sizeToFit()
let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: nil, style: .Done, target: self, action: "closeMessageViewKeyboard")
doneButton.possibleTitles = ["Done"]
var toolbarButtons = NSMutableArray()
toolbarButtons.addObject(doneButton)
keyboardButtonView.items = toolbarButtons as [AnyObject]
messageView.inputAccessoryView = keyboardButtonView
```

The Done button never appears. All I get is a white accessory bar. Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me I create the accessory view using UINavigationBar like this:

```
let navBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, viewWidth, 44))
navBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.BlackTranslucent;
navBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor();
navBar.alpha = 0.9;
//replace viewWidth with view controller width
let navItem = UINavigationItem()
let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, target: self, action: "closeMessageViewKeyboard")
navItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton

navBar.pushNavigationItem(navItem, animated: false)

messageView.inputAccessoryView = navBar
```

Comment: check updated code. I forgot put the frame or UINavigationBar

Comment: Now I see a white bar on top of keyboard but no buttons.

Comment: check updated code, change background color to black

Comment: we are still missing something, bar is now black but still no button

Comment: could you change the way you create the done button to be like this (check updated answer):
let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, target: self, action: "closeMessageViewKeyboard")

Answer (score 0):

1) Add self?
self.messageView.inputAccessoryView = keyboardButtonView

2) You should be able to remove this line:
doneButton.possibleTitles = ["Done"]
and add (title: "done",...) to the line above it.

3) I have similar code and it probably doesn't matter, but, you might add:
keyboardButtonView.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default